# I need help setting up a TCP connection using VB.net to prioritize speed

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I have a high speed controls application I'm working on. Due to the devices chosen, we are forced to use TCP to create sockets. This is my first VB.net app and I'm struggling a little bit.

The device eventually connects but I'm currently testing with 1 of the 8 devices. It takes about 5 minutes just to start the program, and seems to run okay after that.

Here's what I have so far. I loop through and set an array of IPAddresses as strings. I initialize the device status to -1 (No communication). Create a loop to set up all the sockets, try connecting to the TCP client. Using a try and catch here to set the device status and verify which connections are working. Sorry if this is formatted poorly, this is my first time posting on stack overflow. I've been looking for an answer for multiple days and stressing over it.

```
 ' set the server address to the correct device auto increment for the devices and append the string
        For index = 0 To 7
' put this variable in here because it wont let me append a double to a string
            Dim String_index As String = index + 1
            ServerAddress(index) = "XXX.XXX.X.10" & String_index
        Next
        For index = 0 To 7
            DeviceStat(index) = -1
        Next
        ' create a new sending socket
        tcp_SendSocket = New TcpClient
        For i = 0 To 7
            Try
                ' connect the socket
                tcp_SendSocket.Connect(ServerAddress(i), 7000)
                If tcp_SendSocket.Connected = True Then
                    DeviceStat(i) = 1
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                'MessageBox.Show("Ethernet not available. Check network connections.")
                If tcp_SendSocket.Connected = False Then
                    DeviceStat(i) = -1
                End If
            End Try
        Next
```

Comment: Couple thoughts I've got.  First off, very minor performance thing, the two for loops at the start can be combined into one.  Next is a question, when asking about performance it's pretty critical you identify the bottleneck.  When you say 5mins to connect, is that 5mins on executing tcp_SendSocket.Connect.  Have you check with the device supplier for recommended connection methods and settings?  And finally, you've tagged this with vb.net-2010, are you actually using that?  Did you know VS 2022 community is free (with conditions)

Comment: @Hursey, I did combine those now, thanks. Yes it gets stuck on tcp_SendSocket.Connect() in the try statements for each device between 30-seconds and 1 minute. I have checked with the supplier and they don't have any test code, I have the commands manual for it, but thats only for after the connection is made. I have set up to their specs though.  And yeah I am using VS 2022 community, I'll fix the tags.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe that is just the response time of these devices?  Do you have any indication otherwise?

Comment: The previous generations of the device have operated as fast as 8ms response time, and something I forgot to mention is I have created a tcp connection in another form and per device its about 1 second to connect or less.  when I add a loop into the mix, it slows down significantly

Comment: Ahh.. so is the delay on every iteration of the loop? or does it get progressively worse on each pass?  I wonder if this is because you're opening multiple connections using the same instance of TcpClient.  I'm also wondering about the scope here.  See you're connecting to verify, but don't appear to do anything with it

Comment: Might also pay to have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connect?view=net-7.0.  In the remarks specifically talks about the connect method blocking

Comment: @Hursey I wonder if I'm not closing the connections to the device even though I kill the app to debug? I'm using it as part of a callback function, though I'm not sure how to implement that fully yet. I was able to send the specified commands to the device and get messages back in my test app. but that was for the single device. I'll try using different instances and see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the issue. The better thing to do was put the try inside the for loop, the reason is it gave me a better debugging window, where I could view what was happening during each connection. Turns out that the tcpclient was timing out for my other devices, while the device I do have hooked up was connecting in 2ms, so once I get into factory testing it, it shouldn't have any issues. Also slightly cleaner code.

```
 ' set the device ip address array up, this might be an extra step since we turn it into ip address instance and set up device status
    For index = 0 To 7
        Dim String_index As String = index + 1
        ServerAddress(index) = "XXX.XXX.X.10" & String_index
        DeviceStat(index) = -1
    Next

    ' set up the ip addresses as IP address instances instead of strings
    Dim ipAddresses(7) As System.Net.IPAddress
    For i = 0 To (ServerAddress.Length - 1)
        ipAddresses(i) = IPAddress.Parse(ServerAddress(i))
    Next

    'Set up multiple send sockets
    tcp_SendSocket = New TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork)

    'Connect the socket to each device in ipAddresses
    For i = 0 To 7
        Try
            tcp_SendSocket.Connect(ipAddresses(i), 7000)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        If tcp_SendSocket.Connected = False Then
            DeviceStat(i) = -1
        ElseIf tcp_SendSocket.Connected = True Then
            DeviceStat(i) = 1
        End If
    Next
```